# Writing it in a For loop

Tags: php, html, for-loop

This is what I have tried.

```
<option value="Label_0"<?php if (isset($format) && $name == "Label_0") { echo " selected"; } ?>><?php 
                        for($x = 0 ; $x < 24 ; $x++){
                        echo ( "Naam: " . $parcels[$x]['name'] . " || OrderID: ". ($parcels[$x]['order_number'])); 
                        }?></option>
```

I've tried putting this in a loop:

```
<select name="format" id="format">
                    <option value="">Select One</option>
                    <optgroup label="Labels">
                        <option value="Label_0"<?php if (isset($format) && $name == "Label_0") { echo " selected"; } ?>><?php echo ( "Naam: " . $parcels[0]['name'] . " || OrderID: ". ($parcels[0]['order_number'])); ?></option>
                        <option value="Label_1"<?php if (isset($format) && $name == "Label_1") { echo " selected"; } ?>><?php echo ( "Naam: " . $parcels[1]['name'] . " || OrderID: ". ($parcels[1]['order_number'])); ?></option>
                        <option value="Label_2"<?php if (isset($format) && $name == "Label_2") { echo " selected"; } ?>><?php echo ( "Naam: " . $parcels[2]['name'] . " || OrderID: ". ($parcels[2]['order_number'])); ?></option>
                        <option value="Label_3"<?php if (isset($format) && $name == "Label_3") { echo " selected"; } ?>><?php echo ( "Naam: " . $parcels[3]['name'] . " || OrderID: ". ($parcels[3]['order_number'])); ?></option>
                        <option value="Label_4"<?php if (isset($format) && $name == "Label_4") { echo " selected"; } ?>><?php echo ( "Naam: " . $parcels[4]['name'] . " || OrderID: ". ($parcels[4]['order_number'])); ?></option>
                        <option value="Label_5"<?php if (isset($format) && $name == "Label_5") { echo " selected"; } ?>><?php echo ( "Naam: " . $parcels[5]['name'] . " || OrderID: ". ($parcels[5]['order_number'])); ?></option>
                        <option value="Label_6"<?php if (isset($format) && $name == "Label_6") { echo " selected"; } ?>><?php echo ( "Naam: " . $parcels[6]['name'] . " || OrderID: ". ($parcels[6]['order_number'])); ?></option>
                        <option value="Label_7"<?php if (isset($format) && $name == "Label_7") { echo " selected"; } ?>><?php echo ( "Naam: " . $parcels[7]['name'] . " || OrderID: ". ($parcels[7]['order_number'])); ?></option>
                        <option value="Label_8"<?php if (isset($format) && $name == "Label_8") { echo " selected"; } ?>><?php echo ( "Naam: " . $parcels[8]['name'] . " || OrderID: ". ($parcels[8]['order_number'])); ?></option>
                        <option value="Label_9"<?php if (isset($format) && $name == "Label_9") { echo " selected"; } ?>><?php echo ( "Naam: " . $parcels[9]['name'] . " || OrderID: ". ($parcels[9]['order_number'])); ?></option>
                        <option value="Label_10"<?php if (isset($format) && $name == "Label_10") { echo " selected"; } ?>><?php echo ( "Naam: " . $parcels[10]['name'] . " || OrderID: ". ($parcels[10]['order_number'])); ?></option>
                        <option value="Label_11"<?php if (isset($format) && $name == "Label_11") { echo " selected"; } ?>><?php echo ( "Naam: " . $parcels[11]['name'] . " || OrderID: ". ($parcels[11]['order_number'])); ?></option>
                        <option value="Label_12"<?php if (isset($format) && $name == "Label_12") { echo " selected"; } ?>><?php echo ( "Naam: " . $parcels[12]['name'] . " || OrderID: ". ($parcels[12]['order_number'])); ?></option>
                        </optgroup>
                    <input type="submit" value="Send" name "submit" />
```

I keep getting only the last option value and not all. Any issue I am not noticing?

Comment: You want to generate that HTML with a `for`-loop, is that it? You should clarify your question. Also, `// code goes here` doesn't really tell us much what you tried either.

Comment: Unclear to me. What do you put in a loop, the select element? Why?

Comment: @Qirel Yes exactly. Sorry i will update asap the code i did in the for loop.

Comment: @AndyWiesendanger, all I want is cleaner code, with a for-loop(or any other suggestion) I hope i can achieve this instead of having to manually writing every option value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
<select name="format" id="format">
    <option value="">Select One</option>
        <optgroup label="Labels">
            <?php for($x=0; $x<24; $x++){ ?>
            <option value="Label_<?php print $x ?>"<?php if (isset($format) && $name == "Label_" . $x) { echo " selected"; } ?>><?php echo ( "Naam: " . $parcels[$x]['name'] . " || OrderID: ". ($parcels[$x]['order_number'])); ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </optgroup>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Send" name "submit" />
```

I have updated the answer because the value for each option was the same.

[image: Example of code running]

Comment: If you are going to down vote an answer, please explain why

Comment: Thank you for trying. But i get all the Options in 1 line now. (it is 1 option instead of multiple options).

Comment: apologies. your code works nicely ! I can see 1 part inside the option value that i missed. Did not assign the php print $x.

Comment: Yes i noticed the $x , haha